# Csv file 2d array and txt file 2d array comparison

Tags: python, arrays, csv, txt

```
def read_text_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        array = [line.split() for line in file]
    return array

array = read_text_file("file.txt")
print(array[0][1])
```

Gives a list out of range error

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)

print(data[0][1])
```

Why is it the csv file to 2d array works and the txt file doesn't? Just curious

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, remember to paste the full error that you get, also please include the file (or a few lines of it)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the first few lines of both files, as well as the specific error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your inputs we really cannot say for sure, still I can try to approximate what's going on.

Given these TXT and CSV files:

```
file1.txt     file1.csv
=========     =========
foo FOO       foo,FOO  
bar BAR       bar,BAR  
                       
file2.txt     file2.csv
=========     =========
foo           foo      
bar           bar
```

If your program were to read file1.txt and file1.csv, `array` and `data` would look like:

```py
[['foo', 'FOO'], ['bar', 'BAR']]
```

array[0]/data[0] is `['foo', 'FOO']`, and the second item from that, [1], is `FOO`.  **All is well**.

If your program were to read file2.txt and file2.csv, `array` and `data` would look like:

```py
[['foo'], ['bar']]
```

array[0]/data[0] is `['foo']`, and the second item from that, [1], doesn't exist.  **Error, [1] is out of range.**

Here's a similar program I wrote that gives me those results:

```py
import csv


def main():
    print("reading TXT files:")
    print("==================")

    for fname in ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]:
        with open(fname) as f_txt:
            array = [line.split() for line in f_txt]

            try_second_of_first(fname, array)

    print()
    print("reading CSV files:")
    print("==================")

    for fname in ["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]:
        with open(fname, newline="") as f_csv:
            data = list(csv.reader(f_csv))

            try_second_of_first(fname, data)


def try_second_of_first(fname, stuff):
    """Try to print the second "column" from the first line/row of stuff."""
    print(f"{fname}: ", end="")

    try:
        print(stuff[0][1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"could not read {stuff}[0][1]: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
reading TXT files:
==================
file1.txt: FOO
file2.txt: could not read [['foo'], ['bar']][0][1]: list index out of range

reading CSV files:
==================
file1.csv: FOO
file2.csv: could not read [['foo'], ['bar']][0][1]: list index out of range
```

So, there's nothing different in principle between processing your TXT and CSV files, you just appear to be using differently "shaped" data between the two kinds that's giving different results.